# In Getx Flutter how can I get result from function?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I would like to get a percent making two functions.

My first function is a filtered list of my data.

```
int countP(String idC) {
final _ps = ps.where((element) => element.idC == idC);

return _ps.length;}
```

My second function comes from my first function:

```
int countPP(String idC) {
final _ps = ps.where((element) => element.idC == idC);
final _psPd = _ps.where((element) => element.pd != '');

return _psPd.length;}
```

In my view I would like to show the percent:

```
final percentPd =((pCtrl.countPP(idC) * 100) / pCtrl.countP(idC)).round();
```

I need to show the result in Text:

```
Text(percentPd)
```

My question is:

How can I show the result in Text Widget using Getx, because when I open my view the first time doesn't show the result, but if I refresh, yes?

I used Obx, GetX, and GetBuilder in my Text.

I put my controller using Get.find() but doesn't work.
I Used Get.put(Controller) and doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should declare percentPd like this

```
final percentPd = 0.obs;

percentPd.value = ((pCtrl.countPP(idC) * 100) / pCtrl.countP(idC)).round();
```

and then assign it's value afterwards and use Obx on the widget where you want to show it.

Answer (score 0):

In  your widget use this code :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return {
GetBuilder<yourController>(builder: (controller) 
{
    return Text(controller.percentPd)
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Maqsood. How can I call "percentPd.value" in Obx? 

I put final "percentPd = 0.obs;"  in my controller. But how can I get "percentPd.value"?